# Track user position in iOS with installed app - is it possible?

Tags: ios, gps

I have a request from a customer of an app that tracks the users position and send this data to a server. We can assume that the users consent to this and know that they are being tracked.

I know that there's possible to run such tasks in the background of an app when it is not currently active. What's the restriction of this? Can I track GPS-positions for as long as the app is open but not active?

Is there perhaps even possible to track gps-positions without actually running the app. With the only need that it is installed? (I know google did this in the latitude-app if the user did consent.)

I also guess there's integrity issues with this, even if the user consent.

Edit:
Also, what would be the best way to achieve the best location updates possible and still make it to the app-store?

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can track the IOS applications using VOIP. But apple will rejects the application when you want put the application in Apple store.

If you want to distribute the application(Enterprise) you don't face any problem ,but it will impact on the battery of the device.
The following blog helps you.
http://blog.dkaminsky.info/2013/01/27/keep-your-ios-app-running-in-background-forever/

Comment: Thanks, but this is unfortunately not possible since we wanna get to the app-store.